# CNE received unexpected action: android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am very new to android and developing an app which will fetch some data from Firebase realtime database and show data on UI. but whenever app is loaded just nothing happened. In the Logcat window it is continuously
showing:

> D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: received broadcast
>   android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
>
> D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: handleBatteryUpdate
>
> I/BatteryInfoReceiver: ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED
>
> W/QCNEJ: |CORE| CNE received unexpected action:
>
> android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED

i have also tried to search it out but can't understand..
just want to know 
what is the mean of this
"android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED"
 and why its not showing any data on UI.

my firebase realtime database rules (read/write) are set to true. because i am just trying something..

> is there any problem with permissions or manifest file? because i
>    don't have included any of the permissions in app..
>
> i am using my redmi note 4 for testing app.

code for the app is here..

Model class.

```
public class ad {

    private String  adImage, SellerID, price, location, adTitle, adDescription;


    public ad(){

    }


    public ad(String adImage, String seller, String price, String location, String adTitle, String description) {
        this.adImage = adImage;
        this.SellerID = seller;
        this.price = price;
        this.location = location;
        this.adTitle = adTitle;
        this.adDescription = description;
    }

    public String getAdImage() {
        return adImage;
    }

    public void setAdImage(String adImage) {
        this.adImage = adImage;
    }

    public String getSellerID() {
        return SellerID;
    }

    public void setSellerID(String seller) {
        this.SellerID = seller;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getAdTitle() {
        return adTitle;
    }

    public void setAdTitle(String adTitle) {
        this.adTitle = adTitle;
    }

    public String getAdDescription() {
        return adDescription;
    }

    public void setAdDescription(String adDescription) {
        this.adDescription = adDescription;
    }
}
```

my adsViewHolder class

```
public class adsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ImageView ad_image ;
    public TextView ad_title ;
    public TextView ad_price ;
    public TextView ad_location;

    public adsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

         ad_image = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.defPic);
         ad_title = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.adTitle);
         ad_price = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.adPrice);
         ad_location = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.AdCityName);
    }

}
```

my AdsProfile Activity code for fetching and shwoing data on ui.

```
    public class AdsProfile extends AppCompatActivity
            implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

        private RecyclerView AdsListRecyclerView;

        private DatabaseReference mRef;
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ad> options;
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ad, adsViewHolder> adapter;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_ads_profile);



            AdsListRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.Ads_Display_Recycler_View);
            AdsListRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

            mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ads");
            options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ad>()
                    .setQuery(mRef, ad.class).build();

            adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ad, adsViewHolder>(options) {
                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull adsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull ad model) {

                    holder.ad_title.setText(model.getAdTitle());
                    holder.ad_price.setText(model.getPrice());
                    holder.ad_location.setText(model.getLocation());

                }

                @NonNull
                @Override
                public adsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
                    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.ad_layout,viewGroup,false);

                    return new adsViewHolder(view);
                }
            };


            AdsListRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
            adapter.startListening();
            AdsListRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

Comment: please add some relevant code.

Comment: I/BatteryInfoReceiver: ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED ignore this line if your test device connected via a cable or using any emulator. This broadcast is due to increasing charging level. post some code what you did in your code.

Comment: @ReazMurshed 

code added

Comment: @OmInfowaveDevelopers